# How can I call a sprite image by class/id in css?

Tags: html, css, image, sprite

I am now creating a website which are including much tiny images like arrows and buttons. And I have to include all of those tiny images into the same sprite image.

I have used a online tool to create the sprite and I got a css file indicating different images in sprite as output in order to include them in my project.

And I can use the following way to retrieve the sprite image in my html file:

```
<div class='sprite arrow-down'></div>
```

And my question is that. for example, I am now trying to replace an arrow image of my dropdown selector with my sprite.

While the original coding for my selector is styling in this way:

```
.newSelector select{
background: transparent url(../img/button/arrow.png) no-repeat right center;;
width: 75px;
text-align: center;
color:#777777; }
```

That the background of selector is using the image url. How can I replace that url link with the sprite image indicator (class/id) instead of using local links for every small images. Because I have a lot of images calling by the url in css file originally and I am now required to replace them all with the sprite image. But I have no idea how can I work it in a css file or even a javascript file. Please kindly give me some directions or suggestions please. Thank you so much for your time！！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some basic code that uses `background-position`

The image has this arrow sequence: `v-<->-^`

The classes in css have backgrounds in sequence position calculated with  `width * index`. If your sprite grows too big, you can easily solve it with a loop in SASS http://sass-lang.com/

```css
.sprite {
  width: 80px;
  height: 160px;
  background: transparent url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=110&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=v-<->-^&w=350&h=160) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.arrow-down {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.arrow-left {
  background-position: -80px 0;
}
.arrow-right {
  background-position: -160px 0;
}
.arrow-up {
  background-position: -240px 0;
}
img { display: block }
```

```html
<img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=110&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=v-<->-^&w=350&h=160' />
<div class='sprite arrow-up'></div>
<div class='sprite arrow-down'></div>
<div class='sprite arrow-left'></div>
<div class='sprite arrow-right'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you answering my question. I can understand your usage. But how can I implement those arrows into a selector in different classes like my example stated above? I have also tried to add the class "sprite" to my selector div, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry, i realise that I should also included the sprite.png in those relative css as background such that I can use them with background position. it is working now! thank you so much!!!